# Scaffold with TopAppBar integration with Navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-navigation, android-jetpack-compose

How to show navigation icon (BackArrow or Menu) in `TopAppBar` using `Scaffold` based on actual position in NavController? I am using [Navigating with Compose 1.0.0-alpha02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation). Below is a sample code with a description of how it should work

```kotlin
@Composable
fun App()
{
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = "App title") },
                navigationIcon = {

                    /*
                    Check if navController back stack has more
                    than one element. If so show BackButton.
                    Clicking on that button will move back
                     */

                    val canMoveBack = true

                    if (canMoveBack)
                    {
                        IconButton(onClick = {
                            // Move back
                            navController.popBackStack()
                        }) {
                            Icon(asset = Icons.Outlined.ArrowBack)
                        }
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        IconButton(onClick = {
                            // show NavDrawer
                        }) {
                            Icon(asset = Icons.Outlined.Menu)
                        }
                    }
                },
            )
        },
        bodyContent = {
            AppBody(navController)
        }
    )
}
```

I thought about something like `navController.backStack.size` but I got error `NavController.getBackStack can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=androidx.navigation)`.

And the second question, if I wanted to change the `TopAppBar` text do I have to hoist this text and give every "screen" possibility to change this text, or is there any easy built-in way to do this like in the standard View System?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to [Abdelilah El Aissaoui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4907735/abdelilah-el-aissaoui) I have got an idea of how to do it with one `Scaffold` and just changing `bodyContent`. In this method, we don't have to pass `navController` to any body element, everything is done in base App composable. Below is code which enables to navigate between two bodies (Lesson -> Student)

**App:**

```kotlin
@Composable
fun App(
    viewModel: MainViewModel
)
{
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    val baseTitle = "" // stringResource(id = R.string.app_name)
    val (title, setTitle) = remember { mutableStateOf(baseTitle) }

    val (canPop, setCanPop) = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val scaffoldState: ScaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()

    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, _, _ ->
        setCanPop(controller.previousBackStackEntry != null)
    }

    // check navigation state and navigate
    if (viewModel.navigateToStudents.value)
    {
        navController.navigate(route = STUDENT_SCREEN_ROUTE)
        viewModel.studentsNavigated()
    }

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = title) },
                navigationIcon = {

                    if (canPop)
                    {
                        IconButton(onClick = {
                            navController.popBackStack()
                        }) {
                            Icon(asset = Icons.Outlined.ArrowBack)
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        IconButton(onClick = {
                            scaffoldState.drawerState.open()
                        }) {
                            Icon(asset = Icons.Outlined.Menu)
                        }
                    }
                },
            )
        },
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        drawerContent = {
            DrawerContent()
        },
        bodyContent = {
            AppBody(
                viewModel = viewModel,
                navController = navController,
                setTitle = setTitle
            )
        }
    )
}
```

**AppBody**

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AppBody(
    viewModel: MainViewModel,
    navController: NavHostController,
    setTitle: (String) -> Unit,
)
{
    NavHost(
        navController,
        startDestination = LESSON_SCREEN_ROUTE
    ) {
        composable(route = LESSON_SCREEN_ROUTE) {
            LessonBody(
                viewModel = viewModel,
                setTitle = setTitle
            )
        }
        composable(
            route = STUDENT_SCREEN_ROUTE
        ) {
            StudentBody(
                viewModel = viewModel,
                setTitle = setTitle
            )
        }
    }
}
```

In the ViewModel I use this pattern to navigate:

```kotlin
private val _navigateToStudents: MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(false)
val navigateToStudents: State<Boolean> = _navigateToStudents

fun studentsNavigated()
{
    // here we can add any logic after doing navigation
    _navigateToStudents.value = false
}
```

So when I want to navigate to the next fragment I just set `_navigateToStudents.value = true`

Comment: I'm glad you have been able to solve it :)

Answer (score 4):

I was just trying to achieve exactly the same today. I think this code will answer both questions:

```
@Composable
fun NavigationScaffold(
    title: String? = null,
    navController: NavController? = null,
    bodyContent: @Composable (PaddingValues) -> Unit
) {
    val navigationIcon: (@Composable () -> Unit)? =
        if (navController?.previousBackStackEntry != null) {
            {
                IconButton(onClick = {
                    navController.popBackStack()
                }) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowBack)
                }
            }
        } else {
            // this can be null or another component
            // If null, the navigationIcon won't be rendered at all
            null
        }


    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text(text = title.orEmpty())
                },
                navigationIcon = navigationIcon,
            )
        },
        bodyContent = bodyContent
    )
}
```

As you can see, you can provide a title as a String so you don't have to worry about passing a Text composable.

This Scaffold is the base of all my screens and to use it a simply have to write something like that:

```
@Composable
fun Home(navController: NavController) {
    NavigationScaffold(
            title = "Home",
            navController = navController
        ) {
        // Screen's content...
    }
}
```