# determine if is at startDestination in navigation with compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

currently using 1.0.0-alpha08 version of navigation with compose

Does it have a official method to determine if the navHost is at startDestination, or I have to implement my own method to deal with it every time I navigate to a new composable?

Answer (score 0):

found the solution here

```
NavHostController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, _, _ ->
            onStartDestinationFlag.value = (controller.previousBackStackEntry == null)
        }
```

[Scaffold with TopAppBar integration with Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65079798/scaffold-with-topappbar-integration-with-navigation)